# Light switch not working when grounded

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, grounding

I have a light switch connected to a split outlet (one always hot, other controlled by light switch) that appears not to work when the switch is grounded. To be clear, the switch no longer routes power, and the always hot half of the outlet remains working.

I came about this as I was replacing the outlets and switches in my livingroom. I first replaced the outlet as a split outlet, and confirmed that replacement was correct before moving on. Next I went to replace the switch.

The switch is single pole and has 2 wires coming in to it (one black one red). I am assuming the black is hot, and I believe the red goes to the split outlet (I saw a red wire there earlier). The first thing I noticed as odd is that there was a taped off green ground wire in the box.

I decided to untape and attach the ground wire to the switch. The switch does not work.

I unground the switch (but not yet screwed to the box) and the switch operated the outlet just fine.

I screw the switch into the box (I'm assuming it gets grounded by the box), and the switch no longer works.

Any guesses what might be going on?[image]

[image]

Comment: How about providing a few pictures of the switch and switch box.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "split outlet", you mean that it's a duplex receptacle and that one outlet is always hot and the other is switch controlled, right?

Comment: @freeman correct one outlet always hot and the other is switched

Comment: @jack image uploaded

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks squarely into the back of the box please? That'd help us see where that green wire goes...

Comment: It appears that that green wire goes into the group of bare copper grounds so it should be a ground.  Are the backstabs utilized on that switch?  There's an awful  lot of wired crammed  in there and that could affect the backstabs going into the switch and not connecting.

Comment: Hard to see in the second photo, but the green wire pigtails into a bunch of bare copper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the problem was with the switch, there was a bad contact with the switch on once seated. I replaced the switch and everything worked as expected